# angular 4 -using else conditions with ng-template in p-datatable. currently have 2 ngif inside the template, want to avoid using two ngif

Tags: angular

In a component I have a source code similar to this:

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
  <span *ngIf='row.job_id'>
    {{row.job_id}}
  </span>
  <span *ngIf='!row.job_id'>
    Job ID Not available
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

I want to use `else` condition with it inside a single `ng-template`. how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to change the text inside the span you can simple use :

```
{{ row.job_id ? row.job_id : 'Job ID Not available' }}
```

like this you avoid *ngIf

If you really want to use if/else this seem to work :

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
    <span *ngIf='row.job_id; else notAvailable'>
       {{row.job_id}}
    </span>
    <ng-template #notAvailable>
      <span>
        Job ID Not available
      </span>
    <ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the else path in an `ng-template` tag, give it a template variable and then use this: `*ngIf='row.job_id; else elsePath;'`

Something along the lines of this:

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
  <span *ngIf='row.job_id; else elsePath;'>
    {{row.job_id}}
  </span>
  <ng-template #elsePath>
    Job ID Not available
  </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

### Alternatively

Just use a ternary operator:

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
  <span>
    {{ row.job_id ? row.job_id : 'Job ID Not available' }} 
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Using ternary operators save few lines of code.

Comment: Consider marking it as an answer if it fixed your issue.

Comment: how can i apply the same logic for this one too.                                         
  <ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <span *ngIf="row['freq'] === 'one '">{{row['start']}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="row['freq] != 'one '">{{row['start] | date :'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
          </ng-template>